# ARC kills my method-local NSOpenSavePanelDelegate before I can use it. Is there a fix?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using my application delegate as my open-panel file filter. That looked like too many concerns, so I split the panel delegate code to a new class. When setting up my NSOpenPanel objects, I assign their delegate to an object I `alloc`/`init` right there.

I use `-panel:validateURL:error:`, which triggers when I press the "Open" button, to possibly say the given file isn't allowed. I get a crash, `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`, instead. When I added `init` and `dealloc` methods to call `NSLog`, **both** lifetime methods are called before the panel opens.

Is there some non-unusual tweak to let the local object survive through the panel call and the block response? Or do I have to switch back to some sort of global delegate instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> assign their delegate to an object I alloc/init right there.

Most delegate assignments are weak thus ARC is discarding it quickly.

Ask yourself the question "what has a strong reference to the delegate" or "who owns this object"

In your case it's nothing.

The easiest way to fix is to add the delegate as a property of the thing that is creating the panel.

`@property MyDelegateObject *ownedDelegate;`

Comment: This works, too. But it's saying that the delegate has to be relatively global to the method. Since I create multiple instances of this new location, I might as well move the delegate back to an app-global instance.

Comment: It depends. Are your file filters used anywhere other than your open panels? Use and discard objects are better than turning the app delegate into a dumping ground for all those things you don't know what to do with. Your instinct about SOC is very correct. you can always nil out the delegate when your panel is dumped.

Comment: My NSWindowController and NSDocumentController subclasses each have an `-openDocument:` action. Since the delegate is stateless and the document-controller is app-global, I moved the delegate to be a public property of the document-controller so any window-controller can grab it as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using one of the asynchronous methods with a completion handler block, `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` or `beginWithCompletionHandler:`? If so, just put a reference to your delegate object in the completion handler. For example, invoke `-self` on it in an otherwise useless statement.